# Taking a picture with a webcam in Internet Explorer without Adobe Flash

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, web-applications, internet-explorer-11, webcam

Now that Flash is going to be removed from Windows computers, is there a way for web applications to allow pictures to be taken from the user's webcam in Internet Explorer 11?

I know other browsers use WebRTC but that doesn't seem to be an option for IE without some 3rd party WebRTS plugins that people don't seem to have the best things to say about.

Comment: Flash is an ActiveX plugin so you'll have to either (a) Use **C#** to create your own AX with webcam access or (b) Find an already existing ActiveX webcam plugin

Comment: PS: If you get or have SharpDevelop then you can try [this 5-step tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/writing-an-activex-control-in-net/) for making a basic activeX. From there you can also look for webcam image capture tutorials and apply the logic to your AX,

Comment: You can use some existing plugins such as [webrtc-everywhere](https://github.com/sarandogou/webrtc-everywhere) and [Temasys WebRTC Plugin](https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/TWPP/overview). These two plugins add support for WebRTC features to IE and seems don't use flash.